# Detect Numeric Keys in Textbox - VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to detect numeric keys of numpad in textbox keypress event, Actually I just want to allow user to enter numbers from numpad not from alphanumeric pad.

If the numbers are not coming from numpad of the keyboard, event should be cancel.

Is there any way except `GetAsyncKeyState()` to achieve this task?

Currently I'm trying this codes.

```
 If e.KeyChar = Chr(49) Then '48 to 57 are the char codes for "0 to 9" of alphanumeric keypad. 
    e.Handled = True 
 End I
```

The use `GetAsyncKeyState()` is my last priority because it can decrease the performance of my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to check this

1. To check for specific keys instead of characters, use the [KeyCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.keycode(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the KeyDown/KeyUp events for values between [Keys.NumPad0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx) to Keys.NumPad9. KeyPress doesn't provide this property.

   ```
   If (e.KeyCode >= Keys.NumPad0 and e.KeyCode <= Keys.NumPad9) Then ...
   ```
2. If you want to check whether a character is a numeric digit, you can use [Char.IsDigit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0ddtxh(v=vs.110).aspx) to check whether a character is a numeric digit. You can write:

   ```
   If Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Then ....
   ```

Comment: Thank you, The problem is solved, I should have to use `KeyDown` event instead of `keypress`.

Comment: Note: Above doesn't work with KeyDown event.

Comment: @stigzler what doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Keypad 0-9 is Keycode 96 to 105

```
      KEY        CODE
    ------------------
     numpad 0    96
     numpad 1    97
     numpad 2    98
     numpad 3    99
     numpad 4    100
     numpad 5    101
     numpad 6    102
     numpad 7    103
     numpad 8    104
     numpad 9    105
```

---

[**Key and Character Codes vs. Event Types**](http://www.w3.org/2002/09/tests/keys.html)
[**Guide for keycodes**](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

Comment: I know the numpad 0 is 96 and the alphanumeric pad 0 is 47, Problem is how to detect?
My codes returns 47 for both ones (1).